# Realtion of acceleration and deformation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

What will happen if I apply 10N force to a body's one end and 11N to it's others end? Which force will accelerate it, which force will deform it? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Note that

If the body is rigid (zero deformation) then the resultant of the forces $10\ F$ & $11\ F$ may cause the acceleration depending on the magnitude of resultant

If the body is deformable then both the forces $10\ F$ & $11\ F$ may cause deformations  depending on the orientation of forces

Comment: If the forces are acting on the same straight line but from opposite direction to each other, then?

Comment: then the body may have acceleration in the direction of resultant force if the body is sufficiently rigid

Answer (score 0):

The body will move towards the direction of the resultant vector sum of the forces